# microsoft jscript runtime error: redeclaration of const property in asp mvc application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I just opened the project that was running and compiling w/o any issues before, and now when I run it, I get

```
microsoft jscript runtime error: redeclaration of const property
```

Upon closer inspection, I have the same variable declared and defined on two pages inside the Includes section

```
@section Includes {  
      <script type="text/javascript">  

        var detailsPath = "testpathValue";
      </script>     
}
```

I am also getting the same error on a variable that is only defined on one place.

How do I get rid of this JS error, as I mentioned this was not a problem before.

Comment: You need to check your HTML output, whether it really has 2 declarations of the same variable.

Comment: nope, only one for both vars. As I mentioned, this was not a problem before.

Comment: nevermind, got it. I was using an array called history later on and of course IE9 debugger was not showing the correct place where the error occurs.